# Syntax Error when Inserting New Data Into Table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I keep getting a syntax error when I'm trying to insert new entries into the table but I can't seem to figure out why. 
For starters here's the .schema:

```
CREATE TABLE collection (
id int primary key not null,
album text not null,
artist text not null,
year int not null,
cover text 
);
```

And this is the line I've used to add the entry:

```
sqlite> insert into collection(115,"houses of the holy","led zeppelin", 1973, "junk");
```

All the values match up: id int, album text, artist text, year int, cover text. But the terminal just spit out the following syntax error:

```
Error: near "115": syntax error
```

I've also tested putting the int values within quotation marks but I just end up with:

```
Error: near ";": syntax error
```

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are using double quotes instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is incorrect:

```
insert into collection(115,"houses of the holy","led zeppelin", 1973, "junk")
```

First of all, use single-quotes instead of double-quotes:

```
insert into collection (115, 'houses of the holy', 'led zeppelin', 1973, 'junk')
```

Aside from that, the query parser is expecting those values to be the column *names*, and they're not valid as column names.  You should be able to simply include the `VALUES` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO collection VALUES (115, 'houses of the holy', 'led zeppelin', 1973, 'junk')
```

Failing that, explicitly specify the column names:

```
INSERT INTO collection (id, album, artist, year, cover) VALUES (115, 'houses of the holy', 'led zeppelin', 1973, 'junk')
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `VALUES` keyword.

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

For more info see [INSERT DOCS](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_insert.asp)